# wpf notsupportedexception

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

iv'e got an mvvm application ,

**in a viewmodel :**

```
    public CommandViewModel()         
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<CustomerSavedMessage>(this, message =>
        {
            Customers.Add(message.UpdatedCustomer);
        });
    } 

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers 
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set
        {
            _customers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
        }
    }
```

Customers is bound to a combobox in my view .

in a different viewmodel i raise a CustomerSavedMessage on a different thread 
when i attempt to handle the message in the Register's handler delegate above 
a notsupportedexception is thrown with the following message :

```
   {"This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."}
```

i obviously need to use the Dispatcher object for the cross thread operation,
but i can't figure out how this is done from the viewmodel .

also i thought that the framework would know how to handle cross threading between over binding ..

how can i execute the Customers.Add(message.UpdatedCustomer) on the Dispatcher thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to get `Dispatcher` for application's main thread or capture dispatcher in your ViewModel constructor (`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`).

For example:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<CustomerSavedMessage>(this, message =>
{
     Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
         new Action(() => Customers.Add(message.UpdatedCustomer))); 
});
```